# Can anyone identify a recent Supernatural-style TV or cable show?

Tags: story-identification, tv, urban-fantasy

A recent show was on cable or Netflix about a girl whose family started a cult. They were subsequently killed and she became possessed by a demon.

- She was trying to learn of her past and at the end her father came back from hell to take over by using her.
- Any clues to the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the series you are looking for may be called 'South of Hell'. It's got the female lead having a demon inside that was put there by her father.. I've only seen one episode though so I can't confirm the father comes back from hell.